# What kind of spider is this (reddish spider)?

Tags: species-identification, species, arachnology

I just saw this spider on my door and was wondering what kind of spider this is. 
***information***

- Country: The Netherlands (Europe)
- Color: quite reddish (**maybe an idea why this one is reddish?**)

***pictures***
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This most likely is *Microlinyphia pusilla*. Note that this is a male, females look quite different. A picture that closely resembles yours can be found [here](http://bugguide.net/node/view/57260)

[image]
https://www.ispotnature.org/node/402405

And in case you want to know, the Dutch name is 'kleine heidehangmatspin'